# Grails domain custom error messages

Tags: grails, dns

I am working in a grails application, I have many domains in the applications, more than 50! The error message generated are default, I have the following in my message.properties file

```
default.blank.message=Field "{0}" cannot be blank.
```

An example of my one of the domain class is as follows:

```
class Person {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String middleName;
    Date dob;
    String gender;
    String religion;
    String nationality;
    String maritalStatus;

    Zone permAddZone;
    District permAddDistrict;
    String permAddVDC;
}
```

And so on, so when I leave a field, for example 'maritalStatus' the following error message shows up, 'Field "maritialStatus" cannot be blank.'. I also added the following to my message.properties file

```
person.maritialStatus=Maritial Status
```

But still I am getting the 'Field "maritialStatus" cannot be blank.' message. I also tried using I18n Templates Plugin, but as I have a lot of domain classes, modifying error message for all of them would be time consuming. So, what choices do I have or what am I doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to override the field label you need to override the key:

```
<package>.<domainclass>.<fieldname>.label
```

So in your case, try:

```
<package>.Person.martialStatus.label=Label
```

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate message key to override is specified on the reference page for each constraint type. In the case of [blank](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/blank.html) it's

```
com.example.Person.maritalStatus.blank=Marital status must not be blank
```

However this will be very time consuming and repetitive if you have many domains and many properties.

What you are asking for is instead a way to process the domain class property names in some way before they are inserted into the *default* messages.  This isn't something Grails supports out of the box but I like a challenge... and I've found a surprisingly elegant way to implement it.  My approach is the grails plugin available at https://github.com/ianroberts/recursive-messages and it works by extending the format string syntax to support placeholders of the form

```
default.blank.message=Field "{0,message,field.name.}" cannot be blank.
```

A placeholder `{N,message,prefix}` is resolved by prepending the given prefix to the usual placeholder replacement value and then treating the resulting string (`field.name.maritalStatus` in this example) as a no-argument message key, and looking that up in the usual way.  Thus you could have different representations for different languages.

It has to be a plugin because it relies on a trick that works in a plugin's `doWithSpring` but doesn't work in an application's `resources.groovy`, to modify the definition of the default `messageSource` Spring bean.

Disclaimer: this was a quick fix, it hasn't been fully tested and could probably be implemented more efficiently.

Comment: I understand that, doing this for all fields of all the domains could take very long time. I just wanted to rename the field names in the default error message.

Comment: Right, I see what you're getting at now.  It's not supported natively but I found a way to implement it as a plugin - see edited answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried it, but it did not work, i may have done something wrong.